# Override window.open inside an IFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, overriding

I'm using an IFrame that contains a remote page on a different domain (that I have no control of), and it sometimes tries to pop a window using window.open.

Instead of popping the window - I want to dynamically add another IFrame to the page with the URL that the first IFrame was trying to open.

Is there a way to override the IFrame's window.open so I'll be able to 'catch' the URL it tries to pop?

I've tried:

```
var myFrame = document.getElementById("ifrm"); // 'ifrm' is the iframe's ID
myFrame.contentWindow.open = function (url, name, features) { 
    alert(url);
};
```

But it didn't work (no alert, and the iframe still tried to pop the new window)...

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't think you'll be able to do this - cross domain restrictions prevent you from doing pretty much *everything* to the iframe

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

I'm aware of the cross-domain restrictions, I was hoping that its not one of these...

There are quite a few JS gurus around here, I really hope that one of them will suggest a creative way to accomplish that.

Comment: I'm sorry, jitzo. I misunderstood your post when I read it before and mistook your desire to catch a url that the page in the iframe was popping for the desire to catch a url that you were popping in the iframe. I started a vote to delete my response. I'm sorry again

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel it all good, no harm done :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function bindings(newDoc){
    try
    {   
        newDoc.contentWindow.window.open = function (url, name, features,
                                                     replace) { 
            alert(url);
        };
    }
    catch( e )
    {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
}
```

While calling the iFrame, use onload event:

```
<iframe onload="bindings(this)" ... />
```

It throws the error:

> **Permission denied to access property 'open'** in Firefox
>
> **LOG: Permission denied**  in Internet Explorer

Apparently *Dan F* was right.. UA will deny access to the remote (cross-domain) document loaded via iframe.

Comment: Can you provide the link or a mockup?

Comment: Also, try it by replacing `newDoc.window.open` with `frame.frames.window.open`

Comment: Here's a mockup - http://jsfiddle.net/EmkTD/ - I get an error when running frame.frames.window.open (frame is not defined)
I've also tried window.frames.window.open ( http://jsfiddle.net/EmkTD/1 ) - didnt work either...

Comment: :(
Seems like I'll have to find another way around it, maybe parse the file via a curl request on the server. Anyway, thanks a lot for trying to help out! much appreciated